# compiling i3 under cygwin - cannot find libiconv library

Tags: compiling, libraries, cygwin, i3, configure

I am trying to compile i3 version 4.14.1 under Cygwin 2.884 (Windows 7). I have installed needed libiconv library via Cygwin setup but while running ./configure I get this error:

```
configure: error: in `/home/msamec/Downloads/i3-4.14.1/x86_64-unknown cygwin':
configure: error: cannot find the required iconv_open() function despite trying 
to link with -liconv
See `config.log' for more details
```

Any clue what can I do to help it find the library?

I have tried to compile the library libiconv-1.13.1 manually but I have encountered some errors I don't know how to resolve:

```
libtool: link: /bin/gcc -shared  .libs/localcharset.o .libs/relocatable.o      -o .libs/cygcharset-1.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libcharset.dll.a
.libs/relocatable.o: In function `DllMain':
/home/msamec/Downloads/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/./relocatable.c:324: undefined reference to `cygwin_conv_to_posix_path'
/home/msamec/Downloads/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/./relocatable.c:324:(.text+0x113): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cygwin_conv_to_posix_path'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:59: libcharset.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/msamec/Downloads/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:34: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/msamec/Downloads/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset'
make: *** [Makefile:42: lib/localcharset.h] Error 2
```

I have grepped the iconv_open() function name and found it in the cygwin folder

```
/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/iconv.h
```

and also in the libiconv folder

```
/usr/include/iconv.h
```

But for some reason the configure script is not able to find it.

Here is my [config.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f737c36c86d5b13d46899d8ef2e8a5cc)

Here is my iconv.h
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b117d1680954d591f989256b508bfc5

I have checked where is this libary file inconv.h located on Ubuntu. Unlinke in cygwin it is in /lib/ while in cygwin it is here /usr/include/. Tried copying the library to that location but that did not help either. I was able to reproduce the issue on my home Windows 10 as well.

EDIT: Here is the configure file that I am using: [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/mareksamec/20b408bca8798d9c25ed0edc2b9f2502)

Comment: `/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/iconv.h` is only for cross compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is failing as

```
| char iconv_open ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return iconv_open ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6391: /bin/gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c -liconv  -lev  >&5
/tmp/ccz9hxNr.o:conftest.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `iconv_open'
/tmp/ccz9hxNr.o:conftest.c:(.text+0xe): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `iconv_open'
```

is looking for `iconv_open` in the library `libiconv`, wrongly.
The test code should use the provided `/usr/include/iconv.h`
where there is a

```
#define iconv_open libiconv_open
```

and the cygwin library `libiconv` exports:

```
$ objdump -x /usr/lib/libiconv.dll.a | grep iconv_open
[  5](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 libiconv_open_into
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_libiconv_open_into
[  5](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 libiconv_open
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_libiconv_open
```

the symbol `libiconv_open`.
You need to correct the test to use `iconv.h`.

The test is defined in `configure.ac`

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([iconv_open], [iconv], , [AC_MSG_FAILURE([cannot find the required iconv_open() function despite trying to link with -liconv])])
```

a possible workaround is to change it in something that will test both options.

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([iconv_open],[iconv],,
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([libiconv_open],[iconv],,[AC_MSG_FAILURE([cannot find the required iconv_open() function despite trying to link with -liconv])]))
```

Disclaimer: not tested and you need to run `autoreconf` to rebuild `configure`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer matzeri. I am not sure how to modify the test, I cannot find conftest.x anywhere. Do you mean that I should modfiy the configure script?I am still bit of a noob in makefiles and these things, I thought the problem might be in this area (starting on a line 6396 in configure script: `for ac_lib in '' iconv; do
  if test -z "$ac_lib"; then
    ac_res="none required"
  else
    ac_res=-l$ac_lib
    LIBS="-l$ac_lib  $ac_func_search_save_LIBS"
  fi
  if ac_fn_c_try_link "$LINENO"; then :
  ac_cv_search_iconv_open=$ac_res
fi`

Comment: I have added the link to the configure file gist to my original question.

Comment: Thanks for update.This made the configure pass but then I got this error when I ran make: [link](https://gist.github.com/mareksamec/790bdd5f93b3662d65826ee6b4adf1d8)

Comment: Have you overwritten the `/usr/include/iconv.h` ? The content seem to not match with the original cygwin one. Line 79 is a comment.

Comment: I think I probabbly did, I tried to compile it manually because I had no luck with original cygwin implementation. I just installed fresh cygwin in a different folder, and only added libiconv packages. There is no iconv.h in the /usr/include/ I found it only under /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include

Comment: Install `libiconv-devel` package

Comment: Thanks you were right, now the the header file appeared in the correct location /usr/include/iconv.h I will try the compilation now.

Comment: Ok the compilation has passed the iconv.h part. I have other problems, but that can be resolved. Thanks again for big help, I could not get past this for a few months!

Comment: Send a patch to the project upstream, so the next one will have a easier life

Comment: If the answer satisfy you, you should accept it